# Can worker thread run on different CPU core, parallely?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, operating-system

JavaScript introduces `window.Worker` that allows the script to run parallel. Would like to further understand parallelism. Example code is,

```
<script>
   var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
   worker.onmessage = function (event) {
     document.getElementById('result').textContent = event.data;
   };
</script>
```

If the OS follows 1-1 thread model,

### [image]

then, Is the web worker user thread assigned to a dedicated kernel thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 spec has a concept of workers, but does not dictate how they are implemented.

How workers are implemented is down to the browser. An implementation might choose to implement workers:

- as operating system processes
- as operating system threads
- using its own scheduling algorithm (e.g. in a browser written for an OS with multitasking support of its own, like MS-DOS)
- or any other way it chooses

As an example, V8 (as found in Chrome) uses OS threads to implement threads -- so if you look at V8's `posix.cpp` you'll see references to `pthreads`. A typical modern OS usually tries to spread threads across CPU cores.

Comment: _""Javascript" has a concept of threads"_ No, it doesn't. JS is inherently single-threaded. An single instance of an engine might support running scripts in different threads (V8 does AFAIK), but that's more like running two  separate applications as opposed to one with two threads. _"the engine (in your case, the browser)"_ The browser is not the engine. Also workers are not part of the engine.

Comment: Thanks for this entirely appropriate pendantry ;)  I have modified to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. It's up to the browser generally, but the main point is to allow real parallelism and it cannot be achieved without real threads:

Check for example this [google book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KjvlCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=worker+javascript+kernel+thread+mapping&source=bl&ots=dBfAVC8cix&sig=nqgFnoq1BlyTYIY-A8apKqzBSRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7mbS-4JfMAhUIVT4KHZPIA8cQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=worker%20javascript%20kernel%20thread%20mapping&f=false).

Comment: @overexchange : Yes, it's launched when creating the `Worker`.